# How can I see console.log output when running a NestJS app?

Tags: visual-studio-code, nestjs

I'm building my first NestJS app and I see a lot of examples in their docs that use console.log(), but when I add it, there's no output in the terminal. I'm using vscode's terminal.

I've also tried using the built-in Logger and start the app using npm run start:debug, and I see no output from the Logger either. I know that it's reaching my controller because I'm getting a response. Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Comment: What are you using to start the application? Are you piping your output into some file?

Comment: No piping. Was assuming that the output would go to the terminal, no?

Comment: How are you starting the application? What is the full command?

Comment: I've tried npm run start, npm run start:debug

Comment: Do you see the normal Nest startup logs? Are you on the `Terminal` tab of the VSCode terminal? You run the scripts through a command line and not a UI, right? There's so many possibilities I'm not sure what else to ask

Comment: Yes, I do all of this with vscode. Open the nest app folder, open terminal, type 'npm run start', open postman and make a request to my controller, request returns the expected value, but console.log('test') not printing on the terminal tab. I clicked on Output tab, Debug tab, and terminal. No console log

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the server process that's running is not processing stdout

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205967/discussion-between-jay-mcdoniel-and-u84six).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Through discussion we figured out that the server needed to be rebuilt between changes. `npm run start:dev` does the trick just fine.

Answer (score 16):

you better use Logger instead of console.

```
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';

Logger.log('info')
Logger.warn('warning')
Logger.error('something went wrong! ', error)
```

Comment: OP clearly says "I've also tried using the built-in Logger and start the app using npm run start:debug, and I see no output from the Logger either"

Comment: I'm upvoting cause it solved my problem

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue - strangely, it appeared to be a cacheing issue.

In my case I had to:

- delete the `/dist` folder and
- re-run `npm run start:dev`

Both `console.log` and `this.logger.log` instance I setup began working.

Comment: I thought I was getting crazy because none of my consoles worked, but that fixed it, thx

Answer (score 0):

If you are on *Linux* and running VSCode check to make sure you have your terminal configured correctly.

I was having a hard time debugging, logging (using Net's default logger) and console logging, when I remembered that console logging prints to std out. I checked my `settings.json` and sure enough it was incorrectly configured:

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": 
    {
      "bash": {
          "path": "bash",
          "icon": "terminal-bash",
          "color": "terminal.ansiGreen",
          "overrideName": true
      },
    .
    .
    .
    }
```

I needed to have `"/bin/bash"`configured for the `"path"` property in the configuration object. When I changed it to:

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": 
    {
      "bash": {
          "path": ["/bin/bash", "bash"],
          "icon": "terminal-bash",
          "color": "terminal.ansiGreen",
          "overrideName": true
      },
    .
    .
    .
    }
```

I was just fine. Logging began to work, console.log began to work and my debugger had no more unbound break points. It was great!

So my output was getting printed to std out, but the console I was looking at was not connected to std out.