# console.log() function returns Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'log')

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I am working on a NestJS application. And somehow in my code, if I use the console.log function. Not matter what the input is, it returns an error:

```
[Nest] 71101  - 04/03/2023, 2:14:45 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'log')
```

Even for `console.log("OK");`

I would like to know what's the potential causes for this issue and how should I debug it.

For the surrounding code, there is not much. Even if I put it in the first line of the function. It still throw the error. I do have a Winston logger implemented in the code, but it's not used in this service:

```
var winston = require('winston');
var config = {
  host: '',
  port: 2,
  timeout: 3.0,
  requireAckResponse: false, // Add this option to wait response from Fluentd certainly
};
var fluentTransport = require('fluent-logger').support.winstonTransport();
var fluent = new fluentTransport('docker_logs', config);
// Initialize Winston Logger

const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: 'verbose',
  format: winston.format.json(),
  defaultMeta: { service: 'service' },
  transports: [
    fluent,
    // new winston.transports.Console({
    //   format: winston.format.json(),
    // }),
  ],
});
export default logger;
```

Comment: Can you show the code surrounding this? I would assume that something in your code has replaced the `console` global variable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I see console.log output when running a NestJS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59741255/how-can-i-see-console-log-output-when-running-a-nestjs-app)

Comment: @anothermh Hello Anothermh, Thanks for your find. I tried to delete the /dist and rebuild the application however it still persists. And it actually throw an error other than the empty output in the other question.

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Hello Jay, thanks for the comment, I did a project wide search and did not find any potential global variable that replaced the `console`, it does have a Winston logger and I updated the code for the Winston logger above.

Comment: You're ignoring [the top-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68123555/3784008) on that post.

Comment: @anothermh Hello Anothermh, I tried the build-in logger with both normal `npm run start` and `npm run start:dev` and it does not giving any output. But the build-in logger does not throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

In js anybody could override your native objects and functions like

```
 const originalLog = console.log;
 window.console.log = (...args) => originalLog.call(console, 'prefix', ...args);
```

to debug that problem you may first of all look in the inspector to your console object. Alse you could override setter to your **window.console** to pause the js and open the debugger when somebody try to change it

```
const console= window.console; 
Object.defineProperty(window, 'console', {
  get() {
    return console;
  },
  set(newValue) {
      debugger;
  },
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true,
});
```

You should do it on the very beginning (propbably in the header of your html file). Also you could do the same for window.console.log - probably it is overriten too